# When is the commutator subgroup a maximal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group , under what conditions do we have that $G/[G,G]$ is a finite group of prime order  ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This happens if $G/[G,G]=Z/p$ where $p$ is a prime. The expression $G/[G,G]$ can also be seen has the first homology of $G$ in respect with $Z$. Thus, $[G,G]$ is maximal if and only if $H_1(G,Z)=Z/p$ where $p$ is a prime, which can be seen as a condition satisfied by $G$.

Comment: I know that ... but I cannot see what that tells about $[G,G]$ ?

Comment: The question is when can we say that the commutator is a maximal subgroup, the answer: we can say that the commutator is a maximal subgroup if $G/[G,G]=Z/p$ where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Yes , but that is true for any quotient group , I particularly asked for commutator subgroup ....

Comment: The point is that $G/[G,G]$ is always commutative, if you take any subgroup, it is not true, for example, consider a simple group $G$ and $\{1\}$ is maximal, but $G/\{1\}$ is not $Z/p$

Comment: Well if $G=[G,G]$ then $[G,G]$ isn't maximal, as by definition the maximal subroup is different than the original group

Comment: I think the asker is interested which conditions lead to a maximal commutator subgroup, i.e. certain properties of $G$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide : I have edited the question ; could  you please take a look ?